# Why are my strings showing as numbers on certain devices?

Tags: swift, swiftui, enums

I created an enum for my notification types to let the user know if someone followed them, commented, or liked a post. Each value is tied to the corresponding "notificationMessage". On almost every device, this is displaying exactly how I would expect, but at least one person has told me that they see a "1" and "3" next to all notifications regardless of what type of notification it is. I thought it had something to do with the int I assigned the type to, but regardless of the type of notification it shows the same numbers so that doesn't make sense. I also checked Firestore's data for this user and it appears to be the same as other users' data. I am at a loss especially since it's not happening on all devices. (all iPhones and all running iOS 16+) Any ideas??

Here's what they see:
[image]

Here's what they should see:
[image]

**Notification**

```
struct Notification: Identifiable, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    
    var postId: String?
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let type: NotificationType
    let uid: String
    
    var isFollowed: Bool? = false
    var post: Post?
    var user: User?
}

enum NotificationType: Int, Decodable {
    case like
    case comment
    case follow
    
    var notificationMessage: String {
        switch self {
        case .like: return " liked your post."
        case .comment: return " commented on your post."
        case .follow: return " followed you."
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationCell**

```
struct NotificationsCell: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: NotificationCellViewModel
    var isFollowed: Bool { return viewModel.notification.isFollowed ?? false}
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack (alignment: .top) {
            if let user = viewModel.notification.user {
                NavigationLink {
                    LazyView(ProfileView(user: user))
                } label: {
                    KFImage(URL(string: user.profileImageUrl))
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                }
            }
            
            if viewModel.notification.type != .follow {
                if let post = viewModel.notification.post {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyView(FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post)))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(Text(viewModel.notification.user?.fullname ?? "").font   (Font.body2))\(Text(viewModel.notification.type.notificationMessage))\(Text(" "))\(Text((viewModel.timestampString)).foregroundColor(.gray).font(Font.footnote))")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                            .font(Font.body)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    if let user = viewModel.notification.user {
                        NavigationLink {
                            LazyView(ProfileView(user: user))
                        } label: {
                            Text("\(Text(user.fullname).font(Font.body2))\(Text(viewModel.notification.type.notificationMessage))\(Text(" "))\(Text((viewModel.timestampString)).foregroundColor(.gray).font(Font.footnote))")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                .font(Font.body)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            isFollowed ? viewModel.unfollow() : viewModel.follow()
                        }, label: {
                            Text(isFollowed ? "Following" : "Follow Back")
                                .font(Font.button)
                                .padding(4)
                                .foregroundColor(isFollowed ? Color.accentColor: .white)
                                .background(isFollowed ? .white : Color.accentColor)
                        })
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .stroke(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: isFollowed ? 1 : 0)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            if viewModel.notification.type != .follow {
                if let post = viewModel.notification.post {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyView(FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post)))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        KFImage(URL(string: viewModel.notification.post?.imageUrl ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 48)
                            .cornerRadius(6)
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

**NotificationCellViewModel**

```
class NotificationCellViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var notification: Notification
    
    var timestampString: String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: notification.timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
    }
    
    init(notification: Notification) {
        self.notification = notification
        checkIfUserIsFollowed()
        fetchNotificationPost()
        fetchNotificationUser()
    }
    
    func follow() {
        UserService.follow(uid: notification.uid) { _ in
            NotificationsViewModel.uploadNotification(toUid: self.notification.uid, type: .follow)
            self.notification.isFollowed = true
        }
    }
    
    func unfollow() {
        UserService.unfollow(uid: notification.uid) { _ in
            self.notification.isFollowed = false
        }
    }
    
    func checkIfUserIsFollowed() {
        guard notification.type == .follow else { return }
        UserService.checkIfUserIsFollowed(uid: notification.uid) { isFollowed in
            self.notification.isFollowed = isFollowed
        }
    }
    
    func fetchNotificationPost() {
        guard let postId = notification.postId else { return }
        
        COLLECTION_POSTS.document(postId).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            self.notification.post = try? snapshot?.data(as: Post.self)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchNotificationUser() {
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(notification.uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            self.notification.user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which devices are you seeing this issue?

Comment: @yawnobleix iPhone 11 Pro is the only one so far